# What are the best options for storing User&Roles data - in multiple-app enterprise environment

Tags: oauth, architecture, oauth-2.0, soa

This may attract "it depends" answers, so here are the enumerated contexts. Not looking for one size fits all solution, but challenges in these different usecases, which usecase may required ROLES stored locally vs in central oauth2 server etc.

1. An inhouse webapp, used only by employees of the enterprise.
2. An inhouse webapp(client), uses other inhouse microservices within enterprise.
3. An inhouse webapp(client), uses other inhouse microservices outside enterprise.
4. An inhouse webapp(e.g stackoverflow) being used by external users(me), internal admins, internal-curators, external users who's authorization got raised based on their points.
5. Within enterprise, microservice to microservice auth.
6. Outside enterprise microservice to microservice auth.

Comment: I would look at a SSO option.

Answer (score 0):

Any SSO/Authentication authority, with OAuth 2.0 protocol implementation will suffice. Eg. Azure AD, Azure AD B2C or IdentityServer